# Are code signing certificates automatically trusted across the domain if the root CA is trusted?

Tags: active-directory, certificate-authority, ad-certificate-services, certificate

We have a Microsoft enterprise certificate authority, and I would like to start issuing a few code signing certificates.

But what I'm unsure of is this: since all our domain/forest machines trust the internal CA, when I issue code signing certificates: will all the client systems automagically trust the code signing certs for executing any code, or do I need to add the individual users' code signing certs to the clients' "Trusted People" store (like you might do with their self-signed or third-party certs)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you issue the certificates using a trusted CA, then all these certificates will be trusted by your machines. You can have a look at [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_certificate_authorities).

Comment: That's what I suspected... thanks for the confirmation. We'll just have to be careful who we issue the code signing certs to, as they'll be inheriting a lot of power.

Answer (score 0):

It depends... I used to think that way, but then we started using System Center Update Manager. For the cert to be trusted in this case, it needs to be added to the "Trusted Publishers" store even when it's from your CA.

http://mikeshellenberger.wordpress.com/2010/09/02/system-center-updates-publisher-microsoft-pki/

Comment: Hmm... interesting. Guess I'll have to try it and see!

Answer (score 0):

You want to add this to "TrustedPublishers" as well as the "TrustedRoot"

https://www.spreadsheet1.com/how-to-add-certificate-to-trusted-publishers-in-excel.html

```
certutil -addstore "TrustedPublishers" *.cer
```